# Set Wordpress <title> from querystring

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a small problem that I'm looking for help with.

I want the Wordpress page title to be set via the querystring parameter (url). So a link looking like "www.site.com/?title=New dynamic title" should set the title to "New dynamic title". If the word "title" is missing in the query string (url) then the default title should be used.

Can this be done?

Comment: Short answer: "yes". Long answer: "yes, it can be done". What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Basically, it takes the search string (the '?') and removes the '?title=' component leaving just the text after. If you have multiple strings, you'll have to split it up and get only the title.

This should work if it's simple enough:

```
document.title = window.location.search.replace('?title=', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript ?

```
document.title = "This is the new page title.";
```

### edit see marks answer. It's way better

or in wordpress. If it's wordpress you need to add a hook.
have a look at the

[WORDPRESS API DOCS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title)

example

```
<?php add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something working by altering the original code, I just hope it's ok to do the way I did:

```
<title>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['title'])) {
    echo $_GET['title'];
} elseif ( is_category() ) {
    echo theme_locals("category_for")." &quot;"; single_cat_title(); echo '&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    echo theme_locals("tag_for")." &quot;"; single_tag_title(); echo '&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_archive() ) {
    wp_title(''); echo " ".theme_locals("archive")." | "; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_search() ) {
    echo theme_locals("fearch_for")." &quot;".esc_html($s).'&quot; | '; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page()) {
    bloginfo( 'name' ); echo ' | '; bloginfo( 'description' );
}  elseif ( is_404() ) {
    echo theme_locals("error_404")." | "; bloginfo( 'name' );
} elseif ( is_single() ) {
    wp_title('');
} else {
    wp_title( ' | ', true, 'right' ); bloginfo( 'name' );
} ?>
</title>
```